# Initializing a class instance globally in a static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries

I'm implementing the Qt framework's `QTextCodec` in a static library. In order for my implementation of the codec to become registered with `QTextCodec::codecForMib(int)` and `QTextCodec::codecForName(const char *)`, a few things must happen:

- An instance of the codec must be initialized (but not necessarily used).
- The instance must not be deleted or go out of scope.

This appears to be due to the fact that `QTextCodec::QTextCodec()` registers the instance with a dictionary of known codecs. Okay. So if I add a global variable to my application (which is linked with the static lib), unit tests are successful.

However, I'd rather have the global instance in the static library, so apps that link against it don't need to do the legwork themselves. **But I can't figure out how to get a class instance to initialize in a static lib without the application referencing it**.

Neither `QMyTextCodec x` nor `QMyTextCodec *x = new QMyTextCodec` actually initialize an instance of the class, *unless* I reference `x` in my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static variable initialization over a library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202142/static-variable-initialization-over-a-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass options to the MSVC linker through a [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statement and use the [`/include'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) option to force it to link the variable.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:variable_name")
```

This will override the removal of that variable if the `/OPT:REF` optimization flag is used. In order for the `#pragma` statement to work it needs to appear in at least one translation unit (source file) of the project linking to the static library. This can be accomplished by placing it in a header file guaranteed to be included by the project. You will also need to take into account name decoration as the `#pragma` doesn't handle it automatically.

`Init.cpp`

```
QMyTextCodec initvariable;
```

`MainHeader.h`

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:?initvariable@@3VQMyTextCodec@@A")
```

Then in any project that relies on the static library, just include `MainHeader.h`

`ExternalProjectMain.cpp`

```
#include "staticlib/MainHeader.h"
#include "something.h"
...
...
```

Note: If the symbol name is incorrect you will get a unresolved linker error.

### -

According to the GCC documentation you can accomplish similar affects with the `__attribute__` keyword. *I don't have a GCC installation handy to test this however.*

```
QMyTextCodec initvariable __attribute__(externally_visible);
```

Comment: Is this specific to a particular platform (i.e. Visual C++ or is it portable?)

Comment: Guess I'm back to the drawing board for other platforms, but that's a good start. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately your Q was tagged for Virtual-C++ and you didn't request any other platforms so the answer was narrow in scope.

Comment: You now have a solution for GCC as well.

Comment: I can't test the GCC version yet but the #pragma unfortunately does not cause the global in my static lib to be initialized in the application.